# How to parse a Datetime with format "MM/dd/YY" in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

So far I try `new DateFormat("MM/dd/yy").parse('04/03/20')` but it produce 04/03/0020 date.

Comment: How will you be able to tell if that date refers to year 2020 or 1920?

Comment: https://github.com/dart-lang/intl/issues/123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to formate this date using formate method of datetime class. However, you need to convert string to datetime using parse method because datetime formate take datatime as an argument.

Following line help you to achieve desire output:

```
 print(DateFormat("MM/dd/yy")
        .format(DateFormat("MM/dd/yy").parse('04/03/20')));
```

**UPDATE:**

This following code will give result as you expected but it is hard to find out it is 1920 or 2020?

```
 DateTime _dateTime = DateFormat("mm/dd/yy").parse('04/03/20');
    _dateTime = DateTime(2000 + _dateTime.year, _dateTime.month, _dateTime.day);
    print(_dateTime);
```

Comment: What I really need is the DateTime object. Note that if you do  print(DateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(DateFormat("MM/dd/yy").parse('04/03/20'))) the result is the same wrong value '04/03/0020' but I need '04/03/2020'

Comment: How will you be able to tell if that date refers to year 2020 or 1920? as @jamescasia mention. do you want 20 everytime ?

Answer (score 1):

```
var currentDate=DateTime.now().day;
 var currentYear=DateTime.now().year;
 var currentMonth=DateTime.now().month;
 
 String month=currentMonth.toString();
 if(currentMonth<=9){
   month="0$month";
 }

 String yearShort=currentYear.toString().substring(currentYear.toString().length-2);
 String values="$currentDate/$month/$yearShort";
```